# generate stored procedure from SQL server to Hibernate POJOs classes in IntelIJ

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, intellij-idea, generate

I'm looking for the method to generate stored procedures in sql to  Hibernate POJOs classes in IntelIJ, such as

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "addEmployee",
                                procedureName = "postEmployeeElement",
                                resultClasses = Employee.class,
                                parameters = {
                                        @StoredProcedureParameter( name = "employeeID", type = Integer.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN ),
                                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "firstName", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN ),
                                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "lastName", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN ),
                                        @StoredProcedureParameter( name = "address",type = String.class,mode = ParameterMode.IN )}
    )
```

I'm really need, but i can't search any way to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IDE [scripting capabilities](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/extending-the-product-functionality.html) to generate POJO classes from database objects. See [example scripts](https://gist.github.com/virtualadrian/519fe0dc6658fe60500067bee3134c97#file-generatemodelpojo-groovy) and [video](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFfvjZbbCd). Some more information in [related blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2017/11/08/export-data-in-any-way-with-intellij-based-ides/). E.g. when you select a procedure in Database tool window then in `SELECTION` object you should have the `Iterable<com.intellij.database.model.DasRoutine>`. The API for the objects you can see in `openapi.jar` in `<IDE_HOME>\lib` directory.